# Call to free blocks

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

While debugging my code I found that my program frequently crashed during cleanup. By adding some `printf` statements I quickly found out that the program kept crashing on a call to `free` (There where multiple, but it would always crash on one of them).

I `#define`'d `free`, `calloc`, `malloc` and `realloc`, put them in `config.h` and let them print out what they where doing, with `+` for `malloc`, `<>` for `realloc` and `-` for `free`.

These are the results:

```
+ 00a92570
< 00a92570
> 00a93980
< 00a93980
> 00a93980
< 00a93980
> 00a94988
< 00a94988
> 00a96990
< 00a96990
> 00950048
+ 00a92570
+ 00958050
+ 00958458
- 00958458
```

On another run, the program almost completed, but failed on the last line:

```
+ 00ac2570
< 00ac2570
> 00ac3980
< 00ac3980
> 00ac3980
< 00ac3980
> 00ac4988
< 00ac4988
> 00ac6990
< 00ac6990
> 00960048
+ 00ac2570
+ 00968050
+ 00968458
- 00968458
- 00968050
- 00ac2570
- 00960048
```

These are all calls to my string library. First you see my program load in a text file, and then you see it allocating buffers for the tokens I want to parse (Let's pretend it's Name, Age, Adress). After processing the file, the cleanup process starts. What bothers me is that clearly `free` is run on a valid pointer, so why is it crashing? Can `free` crash when you pass it a valid pointer? I am on Windows 10 and compiling with gcc 4.9.3

Comment: But is it a valid pointer? If you `realloc` something, you must make sure **no** other pointer points to the old memory block.

Comment: Time to load up your debugger.

Comment: @StoryTeller What exactly do you mean? I do `void* old = ptr; ptr = realloc(ptr, size); if (ptr == NULL) { ptr = old; return 1; } return 0;`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But I am on windows :c

Comment: @YoYoYonnY you may be surprised to know that Windows development systems also have debuggers.  How do you think that Windows devs. get anything working?

Comment: @MartinJames: Is that a trick question? :(

Comment: @MartinJames But I use Cygwin and MinGW, so that doesn't help me...

Comment: @YoYoYonnY: GDB is available in both of those environments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you, that might work. I really loved Valgrind though :c

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks, classic mistake, I forgot to multiply the realloc size by sizeof type. Still curious as to why this blocks free, though.

Comment: You probably write out of bounds of an allocation somewhere, trashing part of the heap

Comment: @YoYoYonnY: Valgrind is very useful but it is not a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are crashing on free(), the likely causes are:

1. Multiple calls to free for the same block.
2. Calls to free using a block not allocated using malloc() & Co.
3. Calling free using a block that has been corrupted.

The random behavior you describe it typical of this type of problem.

Your best bet it to try using a debugging malloc/free implementation.

Comment: How exactly can a block of memory get corrupted? I wrote to a memory buffer outside it's bounds, does that count as corruption?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Righting before the block is usually the way it happens. However, it can also occur when you write past one block and into another.